# how to make json_normalize build a dataframe from openweather respons

Tags: python, json, serialization

Hi I'm struggling to extract the data from openweather response. I am using json_normalize to to the table but the construction of statement is not clear for me. I managed to divide a peace of data in to smaller portions and to normalize it but I wonder if there is a nice and smooth way of doing it.

```
'daily': [{'dt': 1612432800, 'sunrise': 1612419552, 'sunset': 1612452288,'temp': {'day': -4.21, 'min': -10.24, 'max': -2.31, 'night': -           10.24, 'eve': -5.11, 'morn': -3.43},
                         'feels_like': {'day': -10.78, 'night': -13.48, 'eve': -9.52, 'morn': -11.35}, 'pressure': 1010, 'humidity': 96,
                         'dew_point': -5.84, 'wind_speed': 5.69, 'wind_deg': 13,
                         'weather': [{'id': 601, 'main': 'Snow', 'description': 'snow', 'icon': '13d'}], 'clouds': 100, 'pop': 1,
                         'snow': 10.24, 'uvi': 0.89}, {'dt': 1612519200, 'sunrise': 1612505843, 'sunset': 1612538809,
                          'temp': {'day': -3.7, 'min': -10.24, 'max': -2.6, 'night': -9.09, 'eve': -6.92,'morn': -8.96},
                          'feels_like': {'day': -8.01, 'night': -13.25, 'eve': -10.96, 'morn': -13.11},
                          'pressure': 1023, 'humidity': 98, 'dew_point': -4.64, 'wind_speed': 2.59,
                          'wind_deg': 273, 'weather': [{'id': 802, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'scattered clouds','icon': '03d'}], 'clouds': 29,
                          'pop': 0.16, 'uvi': 0.91},{'dt': 1612605600, 'sunrise': 1612592132, 'sunset': 1612625330,
                         'temp': {'day': -8.27, 'min': -15.93, 'max': -7.49, 'night': -15.93, 'eve': -12.8, 'morn': -10.72},
                         'feels_like': {'day': -12.82, 'night': -20.74, 'eve': -17.38, 'morn': -14.93}, 'pressure': 1024,
                         'humidity': 92, 'dew_point': -11.71, 'wind_speed': 2.21, 'wind_deg': 32,
                         'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds',          'icon': '04d'}], 'clouds': 67,
                         'pop': 0, 'uvi': 0.86}, {'dt': 1612692000, 'sunrise': 1612678420, 'sunset': 1612711851,
                          'temp': {'day': -11.72, 'min': -16.93, 'max': -9.81, 'night': -14.36, 'eve': -11.18,'morn': -16.76},
                          'feels_like': {'day': -17.5, 'night': -20.73, 'eve': -17.09, 'morn': -22},
                          'pressure': 1023, 'humidity': 94, 'dew_point': -13.77, 'wind_speed': 3.65,
                          'wind_deg': 81, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}],                    'clouds': 54, 'pop': 0,'uvi': 0.98}, {'dt': 1612778400, 'sunrise': 1612764705, 'sunset': 1612798372,
                          'temp': {'day': -12.41, 'min': -15.94, 'max': -8.43, 'night': -11.33,'eve': -9.23, 'morn': -15.94},
                           'feels_like': {'day': -20.36, 'night': -19.04, 'eve': -17.44,'morn': -22.64}, 'pressure': 1015, 'humidity': 90,
                          'dew_point': -16.35, 'wind_speed': 6.64, 'wind_deg': 69, 'weather': [{'id': 804, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description':             'overcast clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'clouds': 97, 'pop': 0,'uvi': 1.01},{'dt': 1612864800, 'sunrise': 1612850989,                     'sunset': 1612884894,'temp': {'day': -13.58, 'min': -14.7, 'max': -11.21, 'night': -11.4, 'eve': -11.26, 'morn':                  13.48},'feels_like': {'day': -19.95, 'night': -17.27, 'eve': -17.3, 'morn': -20.35}, 'pressure': 1014,                  'humidity': 94,'dew_point': -15.84, 'wind_speed': 4.33, 'wind_deg': 60,'weather': [{'id': 600, 'main': 'Snow',          'description': 'light snow', 'icon': '13d'}], 'clouds': 100,
                         'pop': 0.73, 'snow': 0.83, 'uvi': 0.98}, {'dt': 1612951200, 'sunrise': 1612937272, 'sunset': 1612971415,
                           'temp': {'day': -13.58, 'min': -17.87, 'max': -11.37,'night': -17.87, 'eve': -13.19, 'morn': -13.34},
                          'feels_like': {'day': -19.11, 'night': -23.19, 'eve': -18.44,'morn': -18.75}, 'pressure': 1021, 'humidity':           94,'dew_point': -15.74, 'wind_speed': 3.14, 'wind_deg': 54, 'weather': [{'id': 600, 'main': 'Snow', 'description':          'light snow', 'icon': '13d'}], 'clouds': 82, 'pop': 0.73,'snow': 0.78, 'uvi': 1},{'dt': 1613037600, 'sunrise':          1613023553, 'sunset': 1613057936,
                         'temp': {'day': -16.26, 'min': -20.28, 'max': -13.32, 'night': -19.55, 'eve': -14.36, 'morn': -19.46},
                         'feels_like': {'day': -22.12, 'night': -25.23, 'eve': -20, 'morn': -24.97}, 'pressure': 1028, 'humidity': 93,
                         'dew_point': -18.8, 'wind_speed': 3.41, 'wind_deg': 77,'weather': [{'id': 801, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description':                'few clouds', 'icon': '02d'}], 'clouds': 18, 'pop': 0,'uvi': 1}]}

day = temp_Json['daily']

data_frame_day = pd.json_normalize(day, 'weather', ['dt', 'sunrise', 'sunset', 'pressure', 'humidity', 'dew_point', 'wind_speed','wind_deg', 'clouds', 'pop', 'snow', 'uvi', ['temp', 'day'],['temp', 'min'],['temp', 'max'], ['temp', 'night'], ['temp', 'eve'], ['temp', 'morn'],['feels_like', 'day'], ['feels_like', 'night'], ['feels_like', 'eve'],['feels_like', 'morn']], errors='ignore')
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\PycharmProjects\Tests\main.py", line 263, in <module>
    data_frame_day = pd.json_normalize(day, 'weather',
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\PycharmProjects\Tests\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 336, in _json_normalize
    _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\PycharmProjects\Tests\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 329, in _recursive_extract
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'snow' is not always present"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would normalize the records:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(day)

# since weather column contains a list we need to transform each element to a row
df = df.explode('weather')

# normalize columns
weather = pd.json_normalize(df['weather']).add_prefix('weather.')
feels_like = pd.json_normalize(df['feels_like']).add_prefix('feels_like.')
temp = pd.json_normalize(df['temp']).add_prefix('temp.')

# join columns together after normalization and drop original unnormalized columns
df_normalized = pd.concat([weather, temp, feels_like, df], axis=1).drop(columns=['weather', 'temp', 'feels_like'])
```

This will give you the normalized dataframe.